# Why does my Next.js (React) component only work when it is in the page?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

In my Next.js project, I'm making circles with Tailwind CSS so I can have switches for different statuses.

```
interface Status {
  status: "online" | "offline" | "idle" | "dnd";
}
const StatusCircle = ({ status }: Status) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
        <div
          className={`m-3 flex h-40 w-40 items-center justify-center rounded-full ${
            status == "online"
              ? "bg-green-500"
              : status == "offline"
              ? "bg-gray-500"
              : status == "idle"
              ? "bg-orange-400"
              : status == "dnd"
              ? "bg-red-500"
              : "bg-gray-500"
          }`}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default StatusCircle;
```

This is the code for the circle which works in the Tailwind playground. I pasted it into my page which works, but my page won't be only a circle so I tried to make the circle as a component and `import` it into the page which is:

```
import StatusCircle from "@/components/StatusCircle";

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusCircle status="online" />
      <div className="m-3 flex h-2 w-2 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-red-500"></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

When I look in dev tools, I do have the component but it just doesn't appear as a circle.

After I changed the state and test, only "dnd" is shown [image] but not "idle", "offline" and "online" even though the tailwind is correct

Comment: Check the `content` section of the tailwind config file. Ensure you are including the components directory. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

Comment: also how to mark your comment as the correct solution, sorry I am new

Comment: Welcome! You can't mark a comment as an accepted answer. It was posted to guide you into a possible solution. It sounds like you figure out what was wrong. Take care!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @dennis-martinez

> Check the content section of the tailwind config file. Ensure you are including the components directory. tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

In your root folder, there should be a tailwind.config.js where you set configurations for tailwind

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", // make sure you have this
  ],
}
```

if you also encounter the same error, make sure you have the components registered at the content field :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replace the ternary to be sure:

```
const StatusCircle = ({ status }: Status) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
        <div
          className={`m-3 flex h-40 w-40 items-center justify-center rounded-full
             ${status == "online" ? "bg-green-500" : ''}
             ${status == "offline" ? "bg-gray-500"  : ''}
             ${status == "idle" ? "bg-orange-400" : ''}
             ${status == "dnd" ? "bg-red-500" : ''}`}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't think it is a correct syntax

Comment: Sorry, my bad, have edited the answer...  try now, please

Comment: I just tested with other conditions, dnd did show at the website but not other states(idle, offline, online)

Comment: Did you try debud the `status` prop with a `console.log`in your component?

Comment: I found out that isn't the problem, it is where "bg-orange-500" or "bg-green-500" or "bg-gray-500" not showing as you see in the edited question

Comment: Change the code again, try replace the ternary, just like the answer

Comment: i got 
```html
<div class="m-3 flex h-40 w-40 items-center justify-center rounded-full false
             false
             bg-orange-400
             false"></div>``` which seems a success but still nothing shown

Comment: if class false is a problem you can do individualy ternaries, like the edited answer